# using arrays of different sizes within a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function, broadcast

I'm trying to write a function that will take a set of arguments from the rows of a 2d array and use them in conjunction with all the elements of a longer 1d array:

```
x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
abc = np.array([[1,2,1],
      [1,3,5],
      [12.5,-6.4,-1.25],
      [4,2,1]])


def quadratic(a, b, c, x):
    return a*(x ** 2) + b*x + c


y = quadratic(abc[:,0], abc[:,1], abc[:,2], x)
```

But this returns:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (100,)
```

When I  manually enter the a, b and c values, I get a 100-element 1d array, so I would expect this to return a (4,100) array. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy the operation `x * y` is performed element wise where one or both values can be *expanded* to make them compatible. This is called broadcasting.
In the example above your arrays have different dimensions (100,0) and (4,3), hence the error.

When multiplying matrixes you should be using [dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) instead.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
abc = np.array([[1,2,1],
      [1,3,5],
      [12.5,-6.4,-1.25],
      [4,2,1]])

np.dot(x, abc[:,0])
```

Answer (score 1):

`abc[:, i]` is of shape (4). You need it to be of shape (4, 1) to broadcast against `x` of shape (100) to produce your desired (4, 100) output---so you will need to do `abc[:, i, None]` to add that extra dimension.

The following should work:

```
y = quadratic(abc[:, 0, None], abc[:, 1, None], abc[:, 2, None], x)
```